# Unable to Connect to a Remote JVM using JStat

Tags: memory-management, jvm, heap-memory, jvm-hotspot, jstat

From the Jstat [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/jstat.html) , jstat can be connected to a local as well as remote JVM. The URI can be formed as

```
 [protocol:][//]lvmid[@hostname[:port]/servername]
```

I have a JVM running on one of the servers (CentOS) with JMX enabled -

```
xyz   23878     1  0 Jun01 ?        04:37:00 java -Xms1g -Xmx1g -XX:NewSize=512m -Xloggc:../9301/logs/gc.log -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=../9301/logs/oom.log **-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=19301 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false** -jar ../0.1.14/xyz-0.1.14.jar -serviceName <name> -dataCenter <name> servicePort 9301
```

I am able to connect to the JVM, **from my local machine**, using JVisualVM which uses a 2 step process -

1. Prompts to add the remote machine via jstatd connection on default port 1099 -> *I am able to do so and server gets added proving RMI Registry is available*
2. After Adding the server, you can add a JMX connection to the JVM on the exposed port -> *Success as JMX is exposed by my program on port 19301 and I am able to view the details*

I am, however, not able to use jstat for the same purpose though.

Running *jstat -gc process_id@servername* gives me the below exception -

```
RMI Registry not available at <servername>:1099
Connection refused to host: <servername>; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

Checked various sources over the net and they talk about having the jstatd 
running which I believe is running as VisualVM was able to add the machine.

**Ques:** How should I frame the [vmid] part in the jstat command to connect

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to run [`jstatd`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/jstatd.html) on a remote host in order to use `jstat`.

Having RMI Registry running is not enough. The Registry is just for *registering* various RMI services. `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote` option starts `jmxrmi` service (which works for VisualVM), but jstat looks for `JStatRemoteHost` service.

Once you've started `jstatd`, use `jstat -options process_id@servername` command to monitor the remote VM.

Comment: Thanks a lot @apangin

I stared jstatd on the server and it worked. I was able to access the JVM remotely via jstat-

 root     23438 19717  0 00:11 pts/1    00:00:00 jstatd -J-Djava.security.policy=all.policy

all.policy had the following content -
grant codebase "file:/opt/jdk/lib/tools.jar" {
         permission java.security.AllPermission;
}; 
The point is to ensure that the file: in the policy file should have the correct path. The jstatd documentation has ".." to provide a generic example which was not needed in my case