# How to print the number of java classes loaded in the JVM of an instance?

Tags: java, docker

I believe there is a command to check the number of java classes loaded on an instance.

I have tried with top -H, jstack.

But they dont print the number of classes loaded, is there a way to check this by a console command?

Answer (score 1):

You’re thinking of the [`jstat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/jstat.html) command:

```
jstat -class vmid
```

Comment: I can execute command "jstat" alone, but if I add the -class vmid or any other, it doesnt let me, any idea? It says "invalid arguments. try `jstat -h to see usage" and when I execute jstat -h it only prints: usage: jstat [--count=<count>]

        count : Amount of jstat lines to run

Comment: That sounds like a different `jstat` command

Comment: What does `which jstat` print for you?

Comment: It prints "which: command not found", maybe this is a different jstat that is on the container, is there another way?

Comment: You could pass the absolute path to the JDK `jstat` command if it’s installed on the container, or run `jstat` on a different machine and [connect remotely to the container running `jstatd`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44690253/unable-to-connect-to-a-remote-jvm-using-jstat), or connect remotely to `jstatd` using a different tool such as [VisualVM](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/applications_remote.html).

Comment: A common thing to do in environments that use containers is to run some kind of instrumentation agent with your application that exports metrics like this to a common monitoring service such as Prometheus